# lspci detects gpu but not clinfo

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I have a PC with a GTX 1080 and Rx 570 4gb. When using `lspci -v | grep VGA` it detects both, but when using `clinfo`, it only shows the 570 and therefore doesn't run server X. I am running the nvidia 470 driver on 20.04 lubuntu, 5.4.0-58-generic. Any help is appreciated.